# Downgrade to older libssl version

Tags: debian, package-management, ssl

I'm getting an error when I try to downgrade my libssl version.

I'm using Deepin 15.4 RC, which is on Debian platform.

I need older libssl because I try to install Estonian ID card software.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: It is not recommended to downgraded ssl libs; that being said, it is hard to trick software dependent in a specific version to use newer versions with symlinks as libssl API can vary between versions. Please add to the post more that like the version you have right now, and the exact version and corresponding file that your software is lacking. We might have other tricks to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two versions of libssl installed; one version for your native architecture, and another for some other architecture. If you didn't do that manually, then you're probably dealing with `amd64` (i.e., 64-bit PC) and `i386` (i.e., 32-bit PC).

Packages of two different architecture can be installed together on Debian and its derivatives, provided that all files that are found in more than one package have *exactly* the same contents. When two packages do not have the same version, the changelog will be different, too, failing this requirement. To fix that, you need to ensure that both packages are up- or downgraded at the same time. You can do this by:

```
apt-get install libssl1.0.0:amd64 libssl1.0.0:i386
```

Comment: Yes there is two libssl versions, I didnt install them.
But I need one libssl more there. 
libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u5_amd64.deb
I have amd64.